# PDO Mysql query formatting ouput for javascript

Tags: mysql

This is proving to be a real mind-bender for me :/
I have a table that contains reports from three different regions, and I need to be able to pull the data out and show it in a bar graph separated by rows found per region per week. After banging my head on the keyboard for 3 days now, I'm admitting defeat and turning to you wonderful people. The closest I came involved querying the database 4 times and the stepping through arrays to try to build the output.

Table:

```
|  id  |  region  |  date        |
|   1  |   West   |  2018-01-06  |
|   2  |   East   |  2018-01-12  |
|   3  |  Midwest |  2018-02-03  |
|   4  |  East    |  2018-02-06  |
|   5  |  West    |  2018-02-16  |
```

etc. 
 I need the data to be formatted as such:

```
{ y: 'weekofyear', west: (rowsfound), east: (rowsfound), midwest: (rowsfound) },
{ y: 'weekofyear', west: (rowsfound),  east: (rowsfound), midwest: (rowsfound) },
{ y: 'weekofyear', west: (rowsfound),  east: (rowsfound), midwest: (rowsfound) },
{ y: 'weekofyear', west: (rowsfound),  east: (rowsfound), midwest: (rowsfound) }
```

Comment: what is `(#rows)` is your JSON? Fix your JSON so it matches your source data.

Comment: Those would be the number of rows found... I've edited them to say "rowsfound"

Comment: whats 'week' ? trust me you get much beter help if you preciesly make you json as it should be related to the source data. We don't like thinking on how your results should be like.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear from the description. The data needs to be separated by week of the year.

Answer (score -1):

I got it working with a pivot table:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT
WEEK(date) as week,
COUNT(IF(region = 'east', id, NULL)) AS east,
COUNT(IF(region = 'west', id, NULL)) AS west,
COUNT(IF(region = 'midwest', id, NULL)) AS midwest
FROM
table 
GROUP BY
WEEK(date);
");

$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
$allweeks[] = $row;
}

$json = json_encode($allweeks); 
print $json;
```